# UIViewAutoresizingMask for pinning a button to bottom right corner

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview

I want to pin a UIButton to bottom right corner of the iPhone screen. Both in 3.5inch and 4inch screens.

Here is the code I wrote. But the button always stays on x=265,y=361 both in iPhone4 and iPhone5.

```
UIImage* plusImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Plus.png"];
UIButton* plusButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[plusButton setImage:plusImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[plusButton setFrame:CGRectMake(265, 361, plusImage.size.width, plusImage.size.height)];
plusButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
[self.view addSubview:plusButton];
```

I've set the autoresizing masks to take flexible top and left margins.But it didnt work. What did I miss? Please help.

Comment: u had passed static x & y values? so it takes the frame as u passed. U must passed the relative x & y.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UIImage* plusImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Plus.png"];
UIButton* plusButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[plusButton setImage:plusImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
CGSize viewSize = self.view.frame.size;
[plusButton setFrame:CGRectMake(viewSize.width - plusImageSize.width, viewSize.height - plusImageSize.height, plusImage.size.width, plusImage.size.height)];
plusButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
[self.view addSubview:plusButton];
```

Try that instead.

Comment: thanks it worked by your code. I see that you have calculated the origin x and y manually. whats the point of Autoresizingmasks then?

Comment: The point of the autoresizing mask is to inform the view of where it should be once its superview is resized. Because you're adding the view after the view is created and sized automatically (to fit Retina 3.5" or Retina 4") then it's not actually being used. I left it in there because it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try  `plusButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin`

Comment: May be this would have been helpful to you if you want to go with autoResizingMask. plusButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin

Answer (score 0):

I've used all those masking as following

```
plusButton.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin;
```

check will it work for me it is working.

Comment: That resizing flag is used for keeping a view centred.